# Keyboard remapping in Lion?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I've used keyremap4macbook for the last few years to turn the right Alt key into a forward delete. Unfortunately, the tool has stopped working in Lion.

Does anybody know of a keyboard remapper that already works in Lion?

Comment: I'm in the same boat, only worse. I have a Japanese keyboard, and the default keymapping doesn't work in the terminal. The backslash key (¥) produces a unknown-symbol box in the terminal. This is actually one of the big things preventing me from upgrading.

Comment: I imagine keyremap4macbook will be updated soon for Lion.

Comment: Wait, never mind. I just installed Lion anyways, and keyremap4macbook seemed to work fine. What problem are you having?

Comment: @Fake Name: It just doesn't work. I can see the prefPane, but I can't make any changes (they revert as soon as the mouse button goes up again), and the only setting I had (Alt -> Forward delete) is not set anymore. I'll try reinstalling it.

Comment: @Fake Name: You were right, it worked. I think I had a really old version installed, and for whatever reason didn't see on the homepage that there were newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had an old version.

The new, officially Lion compatible version from the [keyremap4macbook homepage](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) works fine.